# nodejs - code will be executed before await resolves

Tags: node.js, async-await

I've this piece of code that executes before the await is being resolved.

How can I fix this and execute functions after the awaited results resolve?

```
let trader_positions = await WebRequest(trader_id);

    // setto le posizioni as Unchecked
    console.log('1) Imposto a 0 tutte le posizioni attivr dell utente: ' + nome_trader)
    await DataController.setPositionAsUnchecked(nome_trader);

    if (trader_positions) {
        console.log('2A) Utente ha delle posizioni aperte..')
        await _.map(trader_positions, async function (data) {
                console.log("POZIONI APERTE");
                console.log(data);
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => async function () {
                let resp = await DataController.checkCoin(data, nome_trader);
                await DataController.verificaCoin(resp, data, nome_trader);
                return resolve(true)
            })
        })
    } else {
        console.log('2) utente non ha posizioni aperte')
        return false;
    }
    console.log('executed before await')
```

This is a video that illustrates the flow of execution: https://streamable.com/ji44ej

Comment: You need to await on all promises. Use `Promise.all` with the return value from the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

you're not returning, try this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => async function () {
//...
resolve(true)
```